# IP Address Range (IP Address and Domain Restrictions)

Tags: iis, iis-8

I am trying to add IP address range in **IIS 8.0** i have found some example but didn't understand it, here is the [example link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8d44fb/ip-address-and-domain-restrictions-in-iis-8/) for convenience screen shot is attached and example text is highlighted.  [image: ScreenShot] 
Can any one explain this example?